# Are PHP $_GET methods indexed by search engines?

Tags: php, methods, get

If you use a PHP `$_GET` method, and it saves the string of data to the url box, such as:

```
/net/gallry/aidangig/post.php?title=This+funny+Doge&author=%40aidangig&media_post=Lol+feel+free+to+comment.<img+src%3D"%2Fgallry%2Femojis%2F1f602.svg"+height%3D"16"+width%3D"16"%2F>%0D%0A<img+src%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FANQFVFm.jpg"%2F>%0D%0A
```

Will this be saved, and indexed by Google as it is here, or would Google just index it as:

```
/net/gallry/aidangig/post.php?
```

Comment: if the url is on a page it will be indexed, but google will not submit your forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Google can (and will) index $_GET parameters.

If you manage this site, and you do not wish Google to do so, you can either use [canonical links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066), or you can tell Google which parameters it should ignore within [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/). Note that the second option will not prevent other search engines from indexing these URLs.